# JPA expecting ID column on joined table

Tags: jpa, join, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to represent a join table with JPA, however the generated SQL is expecting an `id` field on one of the tables.

The generated SQL is very close, but appears an ID column is expected on Permission table and used as the FK on the join table, which I was hoping not to do. See schema below:

[image]

You can see I am not using an ID column on permission table, instead letting the text representation of the permission be the key.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int accountId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean admin;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_permission", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission"))
    private List<Permission> permissions;

}
```

**Permission.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Permission {

    @Id
    private String permission;
    private String permissionName;
    private String permissionDescription;

}
```

**Generated SQL**

```
select 
    permission0_.id as id1_2_0_, 
    permission0_.permission as permissi2_2_0_, 
    permission1_.permission as permissi1_0_1_, 
    permission1_.permission_description as permissi2_0_1_, 
    permission1_.permission_name as permissi3_0_1_ 
from user_permission permission0_ 
inner join permission permission1_ on permission0_.permission=permission1_.permission 
where permission0_.id=?
```

**Error**

`ERROR 15056 --- [tp1962586186-25] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'permission0_.id' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was join columns name. It should have been mapped to the mapping tables FK instead of the parent tables PK. Above example is fixed with this change

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_permission",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission"))
private List<Permission> permissions;
```